# Creating and naming column in openpyxl

Tags: python, openpyxl

**Background-**
The following code snippet will iterate over all worksheets in a workbook, and write a formula to every last column -

```
import openpyxl

filename = 'filename.xlsx'
filename_output = 'filename_output.xlsx'
wb = openpyxl.load_workbook(filename)

for sheet in wb.worksheets:
    sheet.insert_cols(sheet.max_column)

    for row in sheet.iter_rows():
        row[-1].value = "=SUMIFS(J:J,M:M,@M:M)"

    wb.save(filename_output)
```

**Question -**
I cannot find documentation on how to name the column. Does anyone know how to achieve this?

**Context -**
I want this column (in each worksheet) to be called 'Calculation'.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get the last column, you can use `sheet.max_column`. Once you have updated the formulas, you can use `sheet.cell(1,col).value = "Calc"` to update the header. Updated code below...

```
import openpyxl

filename = 'filename.xlsx'
filename_output = 'filename_output.xlsx'
wb = openpyxl.load_workbook(filename)

for sheet in wb.worksheets:
    sheet.insert_cols(sheet.max_column)

    for row in sheet.iter_rows():
        row[-1].value = "=SUMIFS(J:J,M:M,@M:M)"
    
    sheet.cell(1,sheet.max_column).value = "Calculation" ## Add line inside FOR loop

wb.save(filename_output)
```

Output would look something like this.

[image]

Comment: This is very helpful, thank you! Question - rather than using `sheet.max_column` how would I define the column? I only ask as when I use `sheet.max_column` the 'Calculation column seems to cut off a column.

Comment: ws.cell() takes in the row (starts at 1) and column (starts at 1). If you want to, you can use max_column+1 or give the specific number like 14 (for column N). For ex. `ws.cell(1,14).value= "Calc"`. Does this help?

Comment: I think my issue is that I am trying to add a column to a range that is already formatted and comprises of Groupings, which is throwing it off. Still though, your answer does answer the question. Just need to worry about formatting next!

Comment: Formatting should not be an issue. You can check [here](https://openpyxl.readthedocs.io/en/stable/styles.html) and/or ask another question. As I can't see the range and grouping, not able to advise more